# How to set axis ticks

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I use matplotlib plot a semilogx figure, the x range is [10,300], because the axis ticket lable is too  intensive in the large range, so  I want to set x ticket lable nonuniform interval,  like this:

x:(20,40,60,80,100,150,300)

it not equality ticks, I find out it can be done in matlab, but how to do in pyrhon?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.xticks`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=xticks#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks).

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(1000), range(1000))
plt.xticks([80,150,300])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That x-axis.... my eyes.... they burn

Comment: @Cyber, I updated the ticks in the code, and chart. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I was just joking around, your answer was fine :)

Comment: thanks a lot! It realy helpful!